# Why can't I deploy the streamlit online?

Tags: python, streamlit

I can run the code locally, but it didn't work when I deployed it online. I guess it was probably caused by reading the data file. I'm not sure where I should put the datasets(csv) for loading.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would guess 1) that you are trying to deploy on Streamlit Cloud and 2) that you are running into an issue with relative paths as described in this forum post:

https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/issues-with-reading-in-dataset-filenotfounderror/12414/2?u=randyzwitch

The issue is resolved by using `pathlib`, as described by the user:

```py
from pathlib import Path

garret_burhenn_pitches_csv = Path(__file__).parents[1] / 'GarretBurhennData/Garret_Burhenn_Pitches.csv'
```